# Loop for scrape

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I want to scrape place by selenium and a lot of place type

```
find = ["Market", "Hyper market", "Night market", "Night market", "Fresh market"]
for place_type in find:
    query = f"{place_type}+nearby+me/@{latitude1},{longitude1},{radius_km1}km"
    url = f"AAA"
    driver.get(url)
    ele = None
    while ele is None:  # retry_next:
        try:
            next_btn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@class="TFQHme "]')
            next_btn.click()
            time.sleep(5)  # Adjust the sleep time as needed
            no_scroll = 3  # Increase or decrease this value to scroll more or less
            for page_down in range(0, no_scroll):
                ele = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                          '//*[@id="QA0Szd"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]')
                driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollBy(0, 5000);', ele)
                time.sleep(2)
        except:
            print("Cannot find next button")
            break
    for i in range(3, 1000, 2):
        address_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                              "//*[@id='QA0Szd']/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]")
        url_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                          "//*[@id='QA0Szd']/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]//a")
        address = address_element.text
        url = url_element.get_attribute("href")
        url = str(url)
        address = address.split('\n')
        print(url)
        # df = pd.DataFrame(url)
        df1.append(url)
        print(address)
        # df2 = pd.DataFrame(address)
        df3.append(address)
    if len(df1) == 0:
        continue
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)
    df3 = pd.DataFrame(df3)
    df4 = pd.concat([df1, df3], axis=1)
    df4['Shop_type'] = place_type
    result_df = result_df.append(df4, ignore_index=True)
result_df.columns = columns
driver.quit()
```

I want to iterate through search queries and search for elements. When the search ends, I want to repeat the next query to create the loop. For example, search for a "market", then grab it in df4, complete it in result_df, and repeat a loop with the next word.  an example would be a word "Hypermarket" , then grab it in df4 and append in result_df then loop to next word and next word and next word until last word then result have 1 dataframe "result_df" where derived from loop to scrape

Scrape Data by selenium and then create result to dataframe

Answer (score 0):

You can use f-strings to inject your search term into the locator.

This solution will only return 1 results per search term. For more either use find_elements() or work with indexing.

For a more detailed answer please provide your application layout (HTML).

```
#loop through search terms
for place_type in find:

    # f - string to build locator depending on search term
    locator_string = f"//*/*[contains(text(),'{place_type}')]"

    # Check that element exist
    if !driver.find_element(By.XPATH, locator_string).isEmpty():
        
        address_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, locator_string)

        # Append the neccessary string
        url_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, locator_string + "//a")
        
        address = address_element.text
        url = url_element.get_attribute("href")
        url = str(url)
        address = address.split('\n')
        print(url)
        # df = pd.DataFrame(url)
        df1.append(url)
        print(address)
        # df2 = pd.DataFrame(address)
        df3.append(address)
if len(df1) == 0:
    continue
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(df3)
df4 = pd.concat([df1, df3], axis=1)
df4['Shop_type'] = place_type
result_df = result_df.append(df4, ignore_index=True)
result_df.columns = columns
```

https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/